# Small java program working as dictionary

Tags: java, arrays

I  want  to do a small code that works like dictionary ,   See how i want to do it

1. want to use  Two arrays    1 For words  and 2  For Meanings
2. When program runs  i will sort the  randomly  eneterd arrays automatically  and then a JoptopnPane  pop up will ask to enter  word from the  Arrays of words .
3. When user  enters word and  Presses enter  it will  search its meaning  in the Second Array .

Arrays  are like this ..

```
String Words[]={"One" , "Two" , "Three", "Four"};
String Meaning[]={"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

I have sorted them, did work in pop up etc, but don't know how to do "matching for word to meaning arrays"

Comment: You can use a `Map<String, String>` to store a mapping of your words and their meanings.

Comment: All caps will attract attention, it's true.  But usually negative attention.

Comment: try Map<String, List<String>> to store a string vs list of strings.

Comment: Really amazing if it got -3 just due to caps .

Answer (score 1):

Simple you need

```
for(int i=0;i<Meaning.length();i++)
if(Meaning[i].equals(word from joptionpane))
{
 /////////////--- ur code................
}
```

Still there alot you have to figure out urself.

Comment: This one looks better as per my scenario

Comment: Ideally a Dictionary search should always be `O(1)`. If you implement it as two parallel arrays, then the whole meaning of `Dictionary` is lost, and the search time will be `O(n)`. It should be implemented as `Mapping` of `Word` and its corresponding `Meaning`, so that search time is `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should rather create a `Map<String, String>` to store mapping of the words and their meanings.

```
Map<String, String> wordMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
   {
        put("One", "1");
        put("Two", "2");
        put("Three", "3");
        put("Four", "4");
   }
};
```

To get a `list` of words to display to user you can use: -

```
wordMap.keySet(); // Returns the Set<String> of all the keys in map
```

And then for a word: - "One", you can get the meaning as:-

```
String wordMeaning = wordMap.get("One");
```

This method doesn't require iterating over the array for each word. And ideally a `Dictionary` should always be a mapping from the `word` to its `mapping` so that search time is `O(1)`.